# Need the query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement similar to these question.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP(EmpId Int, EName varchar(10), Sal Int);

INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(1,'Tom',1000);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(2,'Lucy',1500);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(3,'Frank',2000);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(3,'Frank',3000);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(3,'Frank',4000);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(4,'Jenny',2000);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(5,'Will',1500);
```

There is no constraint on the table.

I need to delete following two rows:

```
 3,Frank,2000
    3,Frank,3000
```

Comment: Do you need to delete only those two rows or rows that have multiple records of the same id?

Comment: "delete from EMP where EName = 'Frank' and Sal in ('2000', '3000')" are you deleting duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to delete duplicates on `empid` and `ename` and keep the one with maximum `sal`.
You can do it with exists:

```
delete from emp e
where exists (
  select 1 from emp
  where empid = e.empid and ename = e.ename and sal > e.sal
)
```